# Addition in Struts2 JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

If a number is less than 10 then I want to print 01,02,etc. Otherwise it will be as it is. I'm trying below code. But problem is that it displays 1,2,etc. This only a partial code.

```
 <s:set var="cnt" value="1" />
 <s:set var="total" value="1" />
 <s:set value="0" var="keyPattern"/>
 <s:set var="cnt1" value="10" />

 <s:iterator begin="1" end="%{iTotalweeks}">
 <s:iterator begin="1" end="7">
 <s:if test='(#cnt-weekStartDay+1)<#cnt1'>  
 <s:set var="day" value='%{#keyPattern+(#cnt-weekStartDay+#total)}'/>
 </s:if>
 <s:else>
 <s:set var="day" value="%{(#cnt-weekStartDay+1)}"/>
 </s:else>
 <s:set var="cnt" value="%{#cnt + 1}"/>
 </s:iterator>
 </s:iterator>
```

where 'weekStartDay' is a action variable. 
If set

```
   <s:set value="'0'" var="keyPattern"/>
```

then it will print 001,011,etc.

Comment: I got it... <s:set value="'0'" var="keyPattern"/> <s:set var="da" value='%{(#cnt-weekStartDay+1)}'/><s:set var="day" value='%{#keyPattern+#da}'/>

Comment: You are making the view layer a mess... try to simplify it by reducing the code, or just use an action method to add the leading zeros

Comment: Then mark this question as solved